# Magento - Custom Product Attributes Won't Display in Product View

Tags: magento

I'm developing a Magento store and for some reason none of my configurable product, associated products are displaying on the configurable product's page.

[image: Hmm...]

- Products are all associated with the configurable product
- Using default attribute set
- Same error regardless of theme/package - and base files have *NOT* been edited.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

I included jQuery for a homepage slider in the miscellaneous scripts field under.

system --> configuration --> design

I've now included jQuery on the cms homepage and it works again.